# HAPROXY does't connect to REDIS

Tags: docker, sockets, redis, tcp, haproxy

I'm trying to have HAPROXY as a proxy server between the clients and Redis server all in my local computer using Docker images so have this following configurations.

```
docker run --name my-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```

HAPROXY config file:

```
defaults REDIS
mode tcp
timeout connect 3s
timeout server 3s
timeout client 3s

# Specifies listening socket for accepting client connections using the default 
# REDIS TCP timeout and backend bk_redis TCP health check.
frontend ft_redis
bind *:6379 name redis
default_backend bk_redis

# Specifies the backend Redis proxy server TCP health settings 
# Ensure it only forward incoming connections to reach a master.
backend bk_redis
option tcp-check
tcp-check connect
tcp-check send PING\r\n
tcp-check expect string PONG
tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
tcp-check expect string role:master
tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
tcp-check expect string OK
server my-redis 127.0.0.1:6379 check inter 1s
```

then i run the Haproxy image

```
docker run -p 3000:6379 -d --name my-running-haproxy  my-haproxy
```

after running a log the following message is giving

```
[NOTICE]   (1) : New worker (9) forked
[NOTICE]   (1) : Loading success.
[WARNING]  (9) : Server bk_redis/my-redis is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, info: " at step 3 of tcp-check (expect string 'PONG')", check duration: 1000ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 2594 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT]    (9) : backend 'bk_redis' has no server available!
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Redis responds to the PING command with "+PONG". In the expect statement you can change "PONG" to "+PONG". The same should be made for "+OK".

To know the different responses you can connect to Redis using telnet and run the commands.

```
telnet localhost 6379
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
PING
+PONG
```

[For more info](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-advanced-redis-health-check/#:%7E:text=Redis%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,check%20for%20redis%20in%20HAProxy.)